# Does the Safari in iOS 8 support superscript element?

Tags: safari, ios8, superscript

I have a problem to display the superscript value in the Safari (iOS 8).

In the IE/Chrome browser:

[image: superscript in the IE]

But Safari iOS8 iPad Air confusing:

[image: superscript in the Safari (iOS8)]

I have tried the below two options to display the superscript value, but both of them cannot fix the issue in iOS8.

Option 1: use the sup element.

```
<span>6<sup>7</sup></span>
```

Option 2: use css to implement the superscript.

```
.sup
{
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0; 
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

So any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had the same problem.  We tested with iOS 8.1 beta and it appears to be fixed, so you may just have to wait for its release!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me try it in iOS 8.1 beta.

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me:

```
span.sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1ex;
}
```